# Is there a Debian Repository with OpenJ9 based Java releases?

Tags: debian, java, repository, debian-buster, deb

Does anyone know if there are any Debian (11 Bullseye) repositories providing the latest and greatest Java builds based on OpenJ9 or did someone perhaps write some scripts for automatically updating it from [IBM's website](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads)?

[AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) as of Java 17 is dead, it is now rebranded as [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) (with a Hotspot-based Java build called Temurin to confuse everyone).

According to their FAQ they

1. will no longer distribute OpenJ9-based builds
2. their .deb repository is not yet up anyway

The only way of getting OpenJ9-based releases as far as I could find is getting the [Semeru builds from IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads) but they don't have a Debian repository, so you have to manually install the .tar.gz each time, which is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same question, and found only half-an-answer.

As of 2023, the openj9-based branch of AdoptOpenJDK/Adoptium is to be found at IBM, named "**semeru**".

Their download page
https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/downloads/?os=Linux however has no .deb packages, nor could I find them in any regular repository.

And, more important, I couldn't any source for security fixes. So, the current situation is: doesn't look production-ready. :(

(I'm glad for any correction that can show me a stable .deb repo with security)